# Nodejs connect to mongoose failed on server(ubuntu), but worked on local

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mlab

I have create a node-pro with node+mongoose+mlab on backend,and vuejs on frontend, it worked on local, however, server can not connected to mlab or mongo.

My server system is Ubuntu, with Nginx server
[image]

[image]

and server did not worked

[image]

Comment: You do realize `Randy` and `a2136521` are user and password right? You should at least censor them in your pictures. Ideally use environment variables por such config.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that I should config environment variables, Could you tell me how and where to config.

Comment: This post may help: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/08/working-with-environment-variables-in-node-js.html. Basically you use variables defined _outside your code_ so things like credentials cannot be stolen. In your case you would ideally interpolate the proper credentials into your connection string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem:
  My server's security group rules' port should be opened, it was why logged network error.

Answer (score 0):

It's only the case of entering proper credentials and it will work. You must be entering wrong credentials. **Beware! It's different than your mongolab username and password**. See what is your username for that particular database.....To fix it,

Go to mongo lab proper database, and then click on Users tab and enter the username shown here as username in the mongolab url and then enter the password. **The password which you entered while creating that particular database is your password** here for mongolab url.

If User's tab does not contain any database user, then you can add the user from the right side tab in corner.

Here's an image for your help.[image]

Comment: I know. It works on local, but not on server. can you show users tab, in the question. paste only that portion after cropping all your page.

Comment: I have posted it in my comment

Comment: I have a question about the connected mongolab url'password, Is it the password I set when I added the user named Randy or Orton?Not my mongolab's account, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. It's when you create a database and add users like Randy or Orton and also provide a password as  you have shown.  This combination will work. It's not your mongolab's account credentials.

Comment: And append that image thing into your question by editing your question again. This should NOT be into answers section, because it is not an answer. so delete that answer. If it does not work, then show me the logs in chat section.

Comment: here at https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/5818250/jabongg?tab=general . This document link will help you, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231544/how-to-start-chat-with-a-particular-user

Comment: Sorry, I'm a newer here, I have solved the issue by opened port in my server's security group's rule, and still thank you for your answers.

Comment: Sure. You should accept your answer. This will help others. Also you should elaborate your answer a more for others to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a new user named 'Orton', and update it on my app.js, it also works.
I don't know if I need to set anything else?
[image]